# Use custom domains in local network

Tags: networking, router, dns, routing, bind

Is their any way to setup a custom domains setup in local network.

For example. I have setup a Window 10 laptop as a server and setup many custom domains like

> 127.0.0.1 webmailadmin.maqbolsols.com
>
> 127.0.0.1 webmail.maqbolsols.com
>
> 127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin.maqbolsols.com

If i add thease in another computer like this:

> 192.168.10.110 webmailadmin.maqbolsols.com

It's works fine in that computer. But if i want to config this on many computers i have to changed config file on all computers. also on other devices like android or mobile phone. Is their any way to config like router or by using some software to add these custom domains to local network???

I am using window 8.1 & 10. Any idea or tricks...

Comment: You need a dns server for this. Either by using Windows Server as OS, or downloading a DNS server software package. A DNS server can also be configured on a router, but you need more than a consumer grade router, unless you can flash it with custom firmware.

Comment: Ok! I have a window server installed. Also i have configured dns server to it. All the clients are configured their. Also works find in that computers. e.g. I only add `127.0.0.1 webmail.maqbolsols.com` to the dns server. All the clients can uses this address. But how for devices that's are not clients e.g some specific laptops or mobile (android) devices. I ment how to config dns server with router. I thinks i have commercial router about `10 mb/s`. Because i am in a company called `Maqbool Solutions (SMC-Pvt) Ltd`. Any helps or tutorial...

Comment: Once the DNS server is installed, all you need to do is configure the device that does DHCP to set the DNS server to your server. If the router does DHCP, then in the router DHCP server, set DNS server to the IP Address of your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can set as below:

1. We can configure a DNS server according to this article [How to Setup and Configure DNS in Windows Server 2012](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/configure-dns-windows-server-2012,5589.html).
2. In the DHCP configuration on the router:

We can set DNS 1 to the IP address of the DNS server we just configured.

We set DNS 2 as the DNS address provided by the operator.

3. The IP addresses of all devices are automatically assigned IP addresses via DHCP.